# Cortana skill Oauth2 error AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'scope'

Tags: oauth-2.0, botframework, microsoft-graph-api, cortana

I just setup my Cortana skill to ask for authentication upon invocation, but I keep getting this error whenever the login screen shows up:

**AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'scope'.**

This is the setup that I have for my skill:

[image: AppDev bot framework setup]

[image: Azure portal setup (Cortana channel)]

I would appreciate your help on this, Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

After following useful Micromuncher's comments/suggestions, I changed the AppID to be the one for my App registration instead of the bot ID. I then added https://www.bing.com/agents/oauth as Reply URL in my App registration in the third party service that I'm authenticating against, then I got a **Resource not defined** error after entering my credentials in Cortana's login prompt, I looked for this error in the web and found out that for OAuth2 the URL must be:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/**v2.0**/authorize

Instead of:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize

And that did the trick, thanks!!

Comment: 1/ Why are you passing openid? 2/ Did you try passing auth bearer in request body? Otherwise,it looks right. The auth url is the important one - and Cortana should be be passing the scopes specified in the above parameter. One more thing to check; are you re-using the app id for the skill as the client id for third party service? Or did you registered a new app? The first is how cortana connects to your skill. The second is for how your skill connects to the managed service. There is no SSO right now.

Comment: I changed the AppId for third party services to use an app registration that I made in the Azure instance where my provider is running, and I got the login screen now, it allowed me to authenticate, but then I get "AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application". My Reply URL in the app registration is "https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect". Any idea? thanks!

Comment: I just added "https://www.bing.com/agents/oauth" and I got now "Something went wrong. I'll need you to sign in with [skill name] again." any idea?

Comment: So for your first reply url - yes - you want it to be `https://www.bing.com/agents/oauth`.  The something went wrong is a good thing.  First, if you have debug turned on for Cortana, look at the message payload for an error.  If it is "timeout", then open you azure portal and get the console (so go to build and open online editor then open console.) See what debug info is dumped to the console.

Comment: If you are behind some corporate internet proxy, you'll want to change the checkbox for "my intranet requires authentication" to true as this will add a header allowing you to auth.  Just guessing before you get at the debug info thru the channel or from the bot via console.